# Sublime Text 3 System Package Location?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

**Where are system packages located in ST3?** I'm well aware of these two:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages`

But I can't find where packages such as HTML or PHP are located. These are system packages that I want to edit. I've seen a number of articles suggesting that I copy the default package, let's say the HTML package for example, to my 'Packages' directory and edit it how I like. I just can't find the package to copy...

I'm running OSX 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion), ST3 Build 3047.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pristine packages in OS X are located in `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages`. If you're going to be fooling around with the contents of them, I very strongly recommend using the [PackageResourceViewer](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. It does all the moving, unzipping, and renaming behind the scenes, and if you set the `"single_command": false` option you'll get all the options you need in the Command Palette. I can't recommend it enough, it's made my life so much easier!

(No, I didn't write it...)

One more bit of advice - don't change any of the pristine packages. Other stuff depends on them, and weird things can break in unexpected ways if you outright delete any of them. Instead, use PRV, and/or create identically-named folders in your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` folder, and override individual files by placing modified versions there instead.

Good luck!